# Mocha-PhantomJS - Cannot find Path and Cannot find variable: Mocha

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, mocha.js, mocha-phantomjs

I have a suite of tests that are running in the browser using Mocha, but now I want to use PhantomJS so I can run my unit tests on our CI server. I am getting a few errors when running the `mocha-phantomjs` command on my test.html file.

This is the first error:

```
Error loading resource file:///Navigation/GetAllNavigation(203). Details: Error 
   opening /Navigation/GetAllNavigation: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

In one of my controllers, I am making a call to a WebApi controller at that url that returns some json data.

The second error is:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Mocha
```

I dont know what is causing this error. Any idea how I can resolve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

My version of Mocha was different from the version that `mocha-phantomjs` was using. After I updated my local version, everything was good!

To expand, I think the first error was being caused by the second.